# How to close a dialogue box from some custom link inside the dialogue box

Tags: winforms, window

I have custom control which I am rendering inside dialogue box.
this custom control has a link lable lnkLable. I want to close the opened window when I click on lnkLable.

right now I am finding the parent of my conrol which will be dialogue control in the end and then calling the dispose method of that, which I don't feel very good technique to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Close()` method on the form to close it.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Control btn = sender as Control;
     Form    frm = btn.Parent as Form;
     frm.Close();
  }
```

If it's a modal dialog you can also close it by calling the `Hide()` method because modal dialogs are automatically destroyed the modal pump exits, and the pump will exit when the dialog is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try using [Control.FindForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx)

You have to remember that the control might not be directly on the form, but inside another container, like a panel, in which case the parent of your control will not be the form.

Once yuo have the instance of the form, rather use [Form.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)